# Solr 4.6 Suggester does not correct spelling

Tags: solr, solrj, autosuggest, solr4, spring-data-solr

I am beginner in Solr. I am using Solr 4.6 and Spring 3.x

Following is my Suggester Config in `solrconfig.xml`

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="field">text</str>
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str> 
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Field and FieldType is configured as below in `schema.xml`

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
             generateWordParts="1" 
             generateNumberParts="1" 
             catenateWords="1" 
             catenateNumbers="1" 
             catenateAll="0" 
             splitOnCaseChange="0"
        />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>

    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have indexed Address data with City, state and Country.

When i execute query for `frgo` at `/suggest`

```
qt=/suggest&spellcheck.q=frgo&spellcheck=true
```

it returns blank response.

**Expected Result:**

```
Fargo, West Fargo
```

Please guide me for the configuration.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you might be having problem with the "**buildOnCommit**". Either place a commit after each update in Solr or make it false. Then restart your Solr and try.

Comment: I tried by making `buildOnCommit` false but still same issue. Do i need to reindex my data?

Comment: Did you restarted your SolrCloud? If possible, try re-indexing.

Comment: yes i did both approaches, but still same result :(

Comment: Did you try with a simple search? it runs?

Comment: Yes simple search is working fine, even it suggest correct spelling